# Inserting data into SharePoint Table using Outlook VBA (how to speed up the process?)

Tags: sql, vba, sharepoint, outlook

I've wrote a macro that takes some data from e-mail body and then instert this data into SharePoint Table.
Scrapping the e-mail body works fine, as well as inserting data to SharePoint - but the inserting part takes a long time (about 2 minutes for each execute).

Here is the code:

```
Public Const sDEMAND_ROLE_GUID As String = "{111111111-2222-3333-4444-111111111111}"
Public Const sSHAREPOINT_SITE As String = "https://randomsharepoint.com/sites/test/"

Sub insertIntoSharePoint()
Dim cn      As ADODB.Connection
Dim sConn   As String
Dim sSQL    As String

sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=0;RetrieveIds=Yes;" & _
"DATABASE=" & sSHAREPOINT_SITE & ";" & _
"List=" & sDEMAND_ROLE_GUID & ";"

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

sSQL = "INSERT INTO [TEST TABLE]([Test1], [Test2], [Test3], [Test4], [Test5], [Test6], [Test7], [Test8], [Test9], [Test10], [Test11])" & _
        "VALUES ('TestVal1', 'TestVal2','TestVal3','TestVal4','TestVal5','TestVal6','TestVal7','TestVal8','TestVal9','TestVal10','TestVal11');"

With cn
    .ConnectionString = sConn
    .Open
    .Execute sSQL 'This is the line that takes most of the runtime'
    .Close
End With

Set cn = Nothing
MsgBox "Item successfully added to SharePoint"
End Sub
```

Is there any way to optimize this code?
Or the slow execution depends only on internet connection/weak computer?
Or do you have any other solution to solve the main problem? (scrapping e-mail body and inserting it into SharePoint List)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, VBA is inherently slow.  Maybe you can just import everything from Outlook to Access/Excel, and then source your SharePoint data from Access/Excel.

On the site where you want to add a spreadsheet based list, go to Settings Office 365 Settings button and then click Add an app.

In the Find an app field, type spreadsheet and then click the search icon Search box magnifying glass icon .
find an app field with Spreadsheet typed in and search button highlighted

In the search results page, click Import Spreadsheet.
Import spreadsheet app highlighted in New apps dialog

In the New app page, type a Name for the list.

The name appears at the top of the list in most views, becomes part of the web address for the list page, and appears in site navigation to help users find the list. You can change the name of a list, but the web address will remain the same.
New app dialog with name and file location filled in, import highlighted

Type an optional Description.

The description appears underneath the name in most views. You can change the description for a list at any time using list settings.

Browse to or type the File location of the spreadsheet. Click Import when done.

The spreadsheet will open in Excel, and you'll see the Import to Windows SharePoint Services List window.

In the Import to Windows SharePoint Services List window, choose Table Range, Range of Cells, or Named Range. If you want to select a range manually, choose Range of Cells, and then click Select Range. In the spreadsheet, click the upper left cell, hold down the Shift key, and select the lower right cell of the range you want.
Excel spreadsheet with range highlighted

The range will appear in the Select Range field. Click Import.
Import to spreadsheet dialog with Import highlighted

After you import a spreadsheet, check the columns of the list to make sure that the data was imported as you expected. For example, you may want to specify that a column contains currency instead of a number. To view or change list settings, open the list, click the List tab or click Settings Office 365 Settings button , and then click List Settings.

The spreadsheet data will appear in a list in SharePoint.
List in SharePoint Online

See the links below for more info.

http://3sharp.com/blog/load-excel-data-into-a-sharepoint-2013-list-fast-and-easy/

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2008.04.access.aspx

Comment: Hey @ryguy72, thanks for very comprehensive answer! I've already resolved this with C# (it loads data in ~4 seconds instead of 1,5minute when using VBA), but I will mark your answer as correct, because for sure it is also a good way to deal with this problem.